# Angular 7 on same url navigation problem?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

**Problem statement :-**

when i am navigation to same url the ngonInit or any other life hook cycles dont work in angular .
**Scenario :-**

i am having a lazy loaded generic module in which content changes according to which link it comes . so i am having multiple buttons with different name pointing to the same component and when i click the button i want the screenname so that i can fetch contenet on the generic component according to the screenname and display it to user .

**Problem i am facing :-**

if the component is open and displaying a sceario and user click on another button which routes to same component the angular life cycle hooks dont work and i cant call api to refresh the data ? so how to achieve this ?

**Solution That i have tried :-**
1. onSamenUrlNavigation Property set to  'Reload' . forRoot()
Then i subscribed to router.event in that generic module and refreshed the data  i have used check that if  it is instance of urlnavigationend .but the problem is  whenever user navigates to leftpen menu and click other button my api gets fired and it can causes problem .

2. added queryparameter with screenname as key but the lifecycle methods dont work
3. added navigationextras but some problem

**so how to fix this problem in angular ?**

Comment: You can invoke the `ngOnInit()` manually after you perform *any* operation that requires a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the NavigationEnd solution, but you can check inside the Event object if the URL the user has navigated to is the correct one for the new API request, e.g.:

```
router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd && event.url.match('path/to/my/component')) {
        this.loadApiData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a smart way but this should work:

1. create separate routing for the same component

   ```
    { path: 'cdconfig/:data' , component: CdpiplelinegraphComponent},
        { path: 'cdconfigflow/:data' , component: CdpiplelinegraphComponent},
   ```
2. while navigating alter the path

   ```
   if(this.router.url.indexOf('/cdconfig/')>-1){
          this.router.navigate(['cdconfigflow',id.name]);
      }else{
          this.router.navigate(['cdconfig',id.name]);
   }
   ```